tLogRow: log only when the row has an error [Talend 7.3]
I have a school project and I must use Talend 7.3 as my ETL.
I am using tLogRow in a job that processes millions of rows. I don't want to lose the errors that might happen when processing a specific row (e.g a misformatted date) among all the other information concerning rows that had no problem.
=> I basically want tLogRow to only display the row info if there were an error. If I need to use other components, please tell me as well ;)
Here is a screenshot of my very simple job:
Talend job with tLogRow
I asked some GPTs about this problem and they recommended tDie, tLogCatcher, etc. but they don't seem to log the errors related to row integration, only the program errors.

Make sure that the checkbox Print content with Log4j is checked in the tLogRow component tab.

And when you execute, in the Advanced Setting tab, check Log4J Level and select Error in the dropdown list.

Another way is to change the log level only for section of your process.
Just before the flow that you want to restrict the log output.
globalMap.put("logLevel", org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().getLevel());
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.ERROR);

After the flow, you restore the original log level.
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel
        ((org.apache.log4j.Level)globalMap.get("logLevel"));

